# [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79a05830

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, unrecognized-selector

> [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b0bb4b0
>   2014-10-15 11:32:53.278 Arabs[635:26220] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b0bb4b0'

Here I am facing this error... please help me

```
NSDictionary *dic=[self.homeDataDictionary objectForKey:@"co_home_business_interview"];
NSArray *firstArray = [dic objectForKey:@"co_home_business"];
NSArray *secondArray = [dic objectForKey:@"co_home_interview"];

TitleButtonLabel *titleLabel1 = [[TitleButtonLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 490, 161, 21)];
titleLabel1.section = indexPath.section;
titleLabel1.row = 1;
[cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel1];
NSString *titlestr=[Utility stringByStrippingHTML:[[firstArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"title"]];
[titleLabel1 setTitle:titlestr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
titleLabel1.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
titleLabel1.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
titleLabel1.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap | UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
[titleLabel1 setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:221/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:26/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[titleLabel1 setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:204/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[titleLabel1 addTarget:self action:@selector(titleButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Read the error. You think you have an `NSArray` but you really have an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Your data structures are messed up . Either [dic objectForKey:@"co_home_business"] is not an array or [dic objectForKey:@"co_home_interview"] is not an array .

Comment: Can you post your response?

Comment: From the error, the object you return from `[dic objectForKey:@"co_home_business"]` is a `NSDictionary` If you tell Objective-C that the object is an array, it will believe you.

Answer (score 2):

One of your variables `firstArray` or `secondArray` do not really point to arrays, but rather dictionaries. Make sure that you really have an array on your hands when you call `objectAtIndex:`

Answer (score 0):

Check data structure of `self.homeDataDictionary` dictionary. How ever if you see that there are `NSDictionaries` in that. You may be missing some brackets `()` i mean an `NSArray` with only one object will looks like `NSDictionary` structure. Verify again that object returning from `self.homeDataDictionary` is `NSDictionary` not an `NSArray`.

Also put an `NSLog` to check return object type before going further.

```
NSArray *firstArray = [dic objectForKey:@"co_home_business"];
NSArray *secondArray = [dic objectForKey:@"co_home_interview"];
```

For above two lines seems to be buggy. Here object `dic` might be `NSArray`. And check for its return value and make sure it is an `NSArray` not `NSDictionary`